# How to join strings to a mixed list in kdb using C API

Tags: c, kdb

I am going through the InterfacingWithC [cookbook](http://code.kx.com/q//interfaces/c-client-for-q/) from Kx, and trying to create a mixed list of two symbols, then append a symbol to it. This keeps crashing my kdb process when I load it in a shared object. So this simple code crashes

```
K msgs =  knk(2, ktn(KS, 0), ktn(KS, 0));
K syms=kK(msgs)[0];
S sym=ss("IBM");
js(&syms, sym); <-- this line seg faults
```

But this code not using a list works just fine

```
K syms=ktn(KS,0);
S sym=ss("IBM");
js(&syms,sym);
```

The way I understand it is that knk gives me a mixed list, and I can access elements of that list using kk function. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer. I was using KXVER version 3 when my kdb version/libs/includes were version 2. I changed that to two and it works fine now. In case it helps someone.